# Is there any library that makes create element from string easy?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to create an element from this html string:

```
<li class="station_li">
    <span class="seq_num"></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_li_link">delete</a>
</li>
```

Now, I have to use:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");  
li.className = "station_li";  
var span = document.createElement("span");  
span.className............  
............
```

this is really boring, is there any js library to make this easier?
NOTE: no jQuery please

Comment: You can use Jquery in that case you can make a Jquery object by passing the string to `$()` function.

Comment: sorry, I can't use jQuery in this project

Comment: So you can use any JS library other than jQuery? Any reason behind that?

Comment: In my company, we use our own js library: http://tangram.baidu.com/  (Chinese)

Comment: Due to the unobstrusive nature of jquery, I don't see a reason, why you couldn't use your company library *and* jquery?!

Comment: then your question should not be "is there any js library to make this easier?" :)

Comment: @Yoshi then the code size will be too big...and will be too confusion

Comment: @wong2, is ASP.NET AJAX acceptable? It has a [createElementFromTemplate()](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/build_dom_with_toolkit_common_library) method that's quite verbose, but still better than creating the whole element structure by hand.

Comment: Then just use `innherHTML` it works in almost any browser and even is html5 standard. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often cheat.

```
function createElmt(html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return div.childNodes[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Tom's solution will not work if the html string consists of siblings, I'd use something like this:

```
function createElmt(htmlStr) {
  var
    helper = document.createElement('div'),
    result = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    i = 0, num;

  helper.innerHTML = htmlStr;

  for (num = helper.childNodes.length; i < num; i += 1) {
    result.appendChild(helper.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true))
  }

  return result;
}

// test
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(
  createElmt('<span>1</span> text-node <span>2</span><span>3</span>')
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zSfdR/

Answer (score 0):

can i suggest the following function if you would like it in pure javascript

```
  function addChild(parent,tn,attrs)
   {
     var e = document.createElement(tn);
      if(attrs)
        {
         for(var attr in attrs)
            {
             e.setAttribute(attr,attrs[attr]);
            }
        }
    parent.appendChild(e);
    return e;
   }
```

Example

```
var li =    addChild(document.getElementById('ul tag id'),'li',{"class" : 'station_li'});
var span =  addChild(li,'span',{"class" : 'seq_num'});
var a =     addChild(li,'a',{ href:"javascript:void(0);" , "class":"remove_li_link"});
a.innerHTML = 'some thing'
```

Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.innerHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0). It used to not be a standard but it is now part of HTML5.

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = "station_li";
li.innerHTML = '<span class="seq_num"></span>\
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_li_link">delete</a>';
```

Or if you need to create many of them,

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
// repeat as necessary:
ul.innerHTML += '<li class="station_li">\
    <span class="seq_num"></span>\
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_li_link">delete</a>\
    </li>';
```

Edit: For better performance, don't keep adding to the innerHTML; instead, build up an array of strings then:

```
ul.innerHTML = arrayOfFragments.join('');
```

[More info on innerHTML from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.innerHTML)